# Number of days of a week in a specific year

Tags: r

I have two columns, `Year` and `weekoftheyear` (0-52). How can I know how many days are present in that particular week of the year, say, the first or last week of 2014?

Comment: You should give more informations if you want a clear help. Does each line of your data frame represent a day ? Is there many lines per day ? Is there days without corresponding lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the week start day adjust below:

```
strptime(paste(my_year,my_week,"Saturday"), "%Y %U %A")-strptime(paste(my_year,my_week,"Sunday"), "%Y %U %A")+1

strptime(paste("2014","1","Saturday"), "%Y %U %A")-strptime(paste("2014","1","Sunday"), "%Y %U %A")+1
Time difference of 7 days
```

same as below

```
strptime(paste("2014","2","Sunday"), "%Y %U %A")-strptime(paste("2014","1","Sunday"), "%Y %U %A")
Time difference of 7 days
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, my issue is resolved now